# Adobe Illustrator Variable Data

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating vape juice labels, i need to automate the names of flavors across 300 labels. some are single line titles some are two lines. I am also warping the text as part of the design. how can I get illustrator to vertically center the text regardless of how many lines of txt are being used. Two lines centers fine, but one line places itself too high and I cant make the adjustments one by one. I know Indesign can do this but does not support warped text.

Comment: are you actually warping it, or would typing on a curved path work?

Answer (score 0):

Find a shop that has XMpie that would process the art for you.
It has a feature that can apply text into an Illustrator or Photoshop linked image Through Indesign.  I think there's even a way that you can play with the software to get everything set up and then the shop only has to do the final merge and output for you: [XMpie uImage](https://www.xmpie.com/products/creative-tools/uimage/)

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, Adobe Illustrator now has a vertical alignment option for area-type textboxes.
The option is inside Area Type Options, it's a little far-removed from the paragaph and justification tools - but at least it is now available.
[image]